# line's value is null while in a method

Tags: c#

Alright, so I made a terribly optimized piece of code that should check the application's current path, list all the .wav files and then have a button that allows me to add the file's full path but problem is, when I try to do Trace.WriteLine(line) it works fine and lists the file names but inside the "addtoNuts" it just sees it as empty and only adds the current directory to the list. I tried just tracing the line but it still just gives me nothing. Code :

```
List<string> nuts = new List<string>();

public fileSelector()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    if (Directory.Exists(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/videos/"))
    {
        string files = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, Directory.GetFiles($"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}/videos/", "*.wav"));
        string files3 = files.Replace($"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}/videos/", "");
        var i = 0;
        using (var reader = new StringReader(files3))
        {
            for (string line = reader.ReadLine(); line != null; line = reader.ReadLine())
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(line);

                TextBlock name = new TextBlock()
                {
                    Text = line.Replace("_", " ").Replace(".wav", ""),
                    FontSize = 20,
                    Width = 500,
                    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
                    Foreground = Brushes.White
                };

                fileList.Children.Add(name);

                Button add = new Button() {
                    Height = 45,
                    Width = 45,
                    Content = new Image
                    {
                        Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri($"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}/Images/newPlaylist.png")),
                        VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center
                    }
                };
                
                void addtoNuts(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
                {
                    nuts.Add($"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().Replace("\\","/")}/{line}");
                    Trace.WriteLine(string.Join("\t", nuts));
                    //Trace.WriteLine(line);
                }

                add.Click += addtoNuts;
                
                i++;

                fileList.Children.Add(add);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you really want to have `addToNuts` be a local method, consider moving it to the end of the `fileSelector` method.  It's position here (in the middle of the outer method, within a `for` loop makes it hard to find and hard to distinguish as a method.  Personally, I'd pull it out of `fileSelector`  completely

Comment: By the way, does your code even compile?  Your declaration if `fileSelector` doesn't include a return type (`public fileSelector()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What should you change to get this working**

```
 Button add = new Button() {
    Height = 45,
    Width = 45,
    Content = new Image
    
    Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri($"Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}/Images/newPlaylist.png")),
    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,

    Tag = line //<- This line here
}
```

And then in your addToNuts function replace *line* with *Button.Tag*

```
void addtoNuts(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      var btn = sender as Button;
      nuts.Add($"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().Replace("\\","/")}/{btn?.Tag}");
                        Trace.WriteLine(string.Join("\t", nuts));
                        //Trace.WriteLine(line);
}
```

**Why was it not working**

When your *for* loop executes it creates numerous buttons and labels. And for each button it creates a click event which points to *addToNuts*.

At the end of *for* loop value of *line* is *null*.

Now when you click on any Button in your list it executes *addToNuts* function and try to get value of variable *line* which is *null* as the loop has already finished.

**What we changed**

Now I assigned value of *line* inside the *for* loop to [Tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag?view=windowsdesktop-5.0#System_Windows_FrameworkElement_Tag) property of Button.

> Tag: Gets or sets an arbitrary object value that can be used to store custom information about this element.

This stored value of *line* inside the button, so when you click on the button it gets the clicked button from *sender* and use its *Tag* value.

**Free Advice :)**

You do not need *StringReader* to iterate over files, you can replace below code -

```
string files = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, Directory.GetFiles($"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}/videos/", "*.wav"));
            string files3 = files.Replace($"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}/videos/", "");
            var i = 0;
            using (var reader = new StringReader(files3))
            {
                for (string line = reader.ReadLine(); line != null; line = reader.ReadLine())
                {
```

With -

```
var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles($"{System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}/videos/", "*.wav");
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var line = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file);
```

You can experiment more with [System.IO.Path()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=net-5.0) to get desired result.